# Cassandra how to increase or decrease a count without Counters?

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I've heard that Cassandra Counters are considered a bad practice due to [performance concerns](https://ably.com/blog/cassandra-counter-columns-nice-in-theory-hazardous-in-practice). Which is a pity as they seem ideal for scenarios where you want to update a count but avoid locks or clashes.

Assuming Counters are not an option what is a good practice? My initial though would be to read the existing value, update it in the code, and write it back to the db. But when run in parallel this approach could override itself. e.g. Current value is `9`, thread A reads it and sets `10`, but at the same time thread B also reads `9` and sets `10`, meaning the end result is `10` rather than `11`.

This is a common problem, often solved with locks/transactions in other dbs. What's the approach taken with Cassandra?